# Owl carousel : change slide on hover dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I´m using dots to navigate the owl carousel 2.
I like to change the navigation from click to hover.
So when I hover the second dot, the carousel jumps to the second slide.
Couldn't find something like this in the documentation.

Are there any easy solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution would be something like this:

```
$('.own-carousel .dot').hover(function() {
    $(this).click();
}, function() {});
```

This simply triggers the click events on hover. I am not sure about the classes `own-carousel` and `dot`, better check those.